# Does every abelian C* algebra have a single self-adjoint generator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, functional-calculus

Does an abelian von Neumann algebra have this property? Is there some interesting class of C* algebras that does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No for $C*$ algebras. If $A$ has a single generator then the maximal ideal space is a subset of $\Bbb C$. So $A=C(K)$ is a counterexample, if $K$ is a compact Hausdorff space not homeomorphic to a subset of $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 5):

Every abelian von Neumann algebra with separable predual is singly-generated: this is a result from von Neumann himself; there is a nice proof in Davidson's *C$^*$-Algebras by Example*.

For abelian C$^*$-algebras, as David mentioned in his answer, the singly-generated unital ones are precisely those $C(K)$ with $K\subset\mathbb C$ compact.